# HTTP authentication on Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc

I am in an apartment that requires [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to access the internet. Is there a way to set up Raspbmc to do this? Otherwise I can't access the internet.

Comment: I suspect you would have to plug your Pi into a monitor, start up the desktop, use a browsers to log so that the network will authorise you. That should last then? Unless you need to do it every single time -- hmm ? NOt sure.

Answer (score 1):

Once a day or similar? Should be able to do that with 'curl' and drop a little script into crontab or run it on startup...

It may be as simple as curl --user name:password http://loginpage.com

See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html